# Spring Boot schedules task from view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, schedule

I want add and delete schedule tasks in runtime from views, is this possible? Maybe someone has an example code or good aticle about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this approach. Instead of adding and deletion scheduled tasks, you may check every minute (or with another precision) actual moment against your views and run necessary tasks immediately. This will be easier. Check Quartz Scheduler, its CronExpression has isSatisfiedBy(Date date) method.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "5 * * * * *) // do not set seconds to zero, cause it may fit xx:yy:59
public void runTasks() {
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(); // or Date now = new Date();
    // check and run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem with you. Maybe, I can provide a not such good solution with the help of redis or database.

In the scheduled task, you can read a flag from redis, then you can decide if continue the task. For example

```
@Scheduled(cron = "....")
void myTask() {
    Boolean flag = readFlagFromRedis(); // you can write the flag into redis or database to control the task
    if (flag) {
    // continue your task
    } 
}
```

then, you can control the tasks schedule in runtime.

Although I don't think this is a beautiful solution, it can meet your requirements